# Need horizontal columns in vertical

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have compiled the data in a table called Employees. Table definition is

```
Name         Age
Sam          25
Mike         28
```

Is it possible to write a query that can give me the output in format

```
SAM
25
MIKE
28
```

I am unable to write this query. Is it possible to do it. 
If not, how can i achieve that.
I can do it using a cursor but it will largely degrade the performance of my proc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easily modified to suite your needs

```
Declare @User table (id int,First_Name varchar(50),Last_Name varchar(50),EMail varchar(50))
Insert into @User values
(1,'John','Smith','john.smith@gmail.com'),
(2,'Jane','Doe'  ,'jane.doe@gmail.com')

Declare @XML xml
Set @XML = (Select * from @User for XML RAW)

Select ID    = r.value('@id','int')
      ,Item  = Attr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
      ,Value = Attr.value('.','varchar(max)') 
 From  @XML.nodes('/row') as A(r)
 Cross Apply A.r.nodes('./@*[local-name(.)!="id"]') as B(Attr)
```

Returns

```
ID  Item        Value
1   First_Name  John
1   Last_Name   Smith
1   EMail       john.smith@gmail.com
2   First_Name  Jane
2   Last_Name   Doe
2   EMail       jane.doe@gmail.com
```

Comment: is it possible to do it without using XML ?. Thanks for the answer..!!

Comment: @NimbleFungus Sure but, but you would have to go Dynamic SQL

Comment: Sure. Thats not a problem.. Kindly help me.

Comment: Added another answer

Answer (score 1):

As requested, but I see little value in it

```
Declare @Table varchar(150) = 'YourTableName'   

Declare @SQL varchar(max) = '>>>'
Select @SQL = Replace(@SQL + SQL ,'>>>Union All ','')
 From (Select Seq=ORDINAL_POSITION,SQL='Union All Select Value=cast(['+Column_Name+'] as varchar(500)) From ['+Table_Schema+'].['+Table_Name+']' From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where Table_Name=@Table) A
 Order By Seq

--Print @SQL
Exec(@SQL)
```

Sample Return

```
Value
22 Star Ave, Riverside, RI 02915
22 Planet Ave, Riverside, RI 02915
100 Peck Ave, Riverside, RI 02915
1086 Willett Ave, Riverside, RI 02915
4
5
6
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are correct. The below one is working like charm.

Comment: Cheers.. Thanks a lot.